# How to use php java bridge bridge with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-java-bridge

Is there any way to use php java bridge with CI?
I have a simple php project in Netbeanse which runs good with php java bridge.
First i run javaClass.jar file and then runs the php simple project it works fine.
Where jar files do following things

- Connect to a remote database using JDBC
- return results to index.php

From index.php i call different functions of java class and get the required data

php code

```
require_once("Java.inc");
$demo = new java("javabridgedemo.JavaBridgeDemo"); // it is `package name.class name`
$demo = java("javabridgedemo.JavaBridgeDemo")->testString(); 
java("javabridgedemo.JavaBridgeDemo")->createConnection();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Username;";
$result = java("javabridgedemo.JavaBridgeDemo")->getResult($sql);
```

Now i have to add java bridge with CI in netbeans